# Prevent functionality of other page elements, when modal window is shown

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, overlay

I am new to JavaScript. And I have a modal window popping up when my required form fields are not filled out correctly (this is programmed partly with Ruby on Rails). So, the window shows up, but when it happens, this grey background is not overlaying the page content, like with my other modal here:

[image]

Instead, all page elements remain active, and the error content will add up if I click my buttons.

[image]

Also, if I click another button causing the second modal to show, this will appear just above the errors modal. This is a mess. If I add bootstrap class to my modal in the html.erb file, the modal won't appear. Those are my code snippets, in charge of this modal.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  if (!modal) return;
    
  var close = modal.querySelector(".dismiss-close");
  var modalBody = modal.querySelector(".modal-body");
  var modalContent = modal.querySelector(".modal-content");
    
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        modalBody.removeChild(modalBody.querySelector('#alertElement'))
    }
  }
    
  function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modalBody.removeChild(modalBody.querySelector('#alertElement'));    
  }
    
  modalContent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
    
  close.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
  modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
    
});
```

Another one:

```
var errors = <%= error_messages.to_json.html_safe %>;

var errorForm = document.querySelector('#myModal');
var modalBody = errorForm.querySelector('.modal-body');
var alertElement = document.createElement('div')
alertElement.id = "alertElement";
alertElement.classList.add('alert');
alertElement.classList.add('alert-danger');
modalBody.appendChild(alertElement);
var errList = document.createElement('ul');
alertElement.appendChild(errList)

errors.forEach(function(error) {
var errElement = document.createElement('li');
errElement.innerText = error;
errList.appendChild(errElement)
})

errorForm.style.display = "block";
```

And my html.erb file

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="notification">Please finalise your personal information.</p>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">     
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dismiss-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="center-items-register-second">

    <%= form_for(@user, url: wizard_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages" %>
   

        <div class="row second 1">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="field wizard">
                <%= f.label :street, class: 'required'%><br />
                <%= f.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field housenumber">
                    <%= f.label :house_number, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :house_number, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row second 2">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard">
                    <%= f.label :city, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard zipcode">
                    <%= f.label :zip_code, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :zip_code, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
            

            <div class="row btns second 3">
                <div class="column btns">
                
                     <%= f.submit "Register", class: 'btn form margin second'%>
                
                </div>
                <% end %>
                <div class="column btns">
                    <%= link_to "Quit", @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Your data won't be saved! Are you sure you want to quit registration process?", title: " " },  class: 'btn form margin second' %>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In case of the confirmation modal, I worked with a gem and the feature I needed just came with the bootstrap modal. But my errors modal doesn't have this grey overlay feature somehow. How do I disable page content (especially buttons), while modal is shown? Thanks!

Comment: This overlay is intentional to cover all other page elements from being disabled from user. Compare codes. Maybe you missed adding overlay element to page?

Comment: Yes, that's the "fade"-bootstrap class. But if I add it to my html, modal won't show up at all. Also not if I define fade in css.

Comment: Don't you have already working modal? Reuse that code to place it properly.

Comment: As I explaned above, those are different. The working modal is a confirmation modal, which won't display customised errors, just a hard-coded text. Also, the working modal was created with a help of a gem and a short tutorial, these are not relevant for my errors-modal, unfortunately. I need another solution, which would also uncover for me a reason, why bootstrap fade-class destroys JavaScript. I see there the essence of my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the second sample of the Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/

It seems the data attribute of your button must be changed to:

```html
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button</button>
```

This is required to open the modal with the fade class properly.